Firebase Cloud Function Not Sending Cloud Messaging
So as the title says, the cloud function triggers fine, logs are all 200 ok. The code itself works and it does check the Firestore for relevant updates. And I also tried manually send a Cloud Messaging with same tokens and parameters through Firebase Console, and I recieved the message but not with the Cloud Function, why?
Is it because I have 2 collection dependencies? I made sure the conditions are met, so I dont understand really. Here is the Function code:
exports.visitorNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('posts/{postId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const oldValue = change.before.data();
    const userId = newValue.userId;

    console.log(`new value: ${JSON.stringify(newValue)} old value ${JSON.stringify(oldValue)}`);

    // Check if the post views reach 5, 10, 50, and 100, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000
    const viewsThresholds = [5, 10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000];
    for (const threshold of viewsThresholds) {
      if (newValue.views >= threshold && oldValue.views < threshold) {
        const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`notifications/${userId}`);
        const doc = await userRef.get();

        if (doc.exists && doc.data().visitorNotification) {
          console.log(`Doc exists and notifications enabled`);
          const message = {
            notification: {
              title: 'Hello',
              body: `Your post "${newValue.title}" has ${threshold} views.`,
            },
            token: doc.data().currentToken,
          };

          try {
            const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
  });

